# Black screen when splitting media files

Tags: ffmpeg, media

When I run

```
for i in $(ls *mp4);
    do ffmpeg -i $i -ss 0 -t 720.0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy $i-part1.mp4;
    ffmpeg -i $i -ss 720.0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy $i-part2.mp4;
done;
```

in a directory of some mp4-files I get a ~3 second black screen with audio at the beginning of the part2 clips, how can I fix this? Am I missing something in my script?

Comment: Is there any chance that any of your filenames contain spaces? This probably isn't your problem, but, in general, `for i in *mp4` is better than `for i in $(ls *mp4)`, and `"$i"` is better than `$i`.

Comment: No spaces and still the same problem.